# how to understand arrival rate about apache storm disruptor queue

Tags: apache-storm

About storm metric. I do not understand the relationship between send queue arrival rate and receive queue arrival rate.
For example,  when open ACK, if a spout receive one tuple , and it emit one tuple. whether the RQ arrival rate : SQ arrival rate = 1:2?

Besides, if system not stable. this Equation may be change?

Answer (score 1):

Spout instances in Storm do not have a receive queue (only a send queue)? I assume you are referring to bolts?

Although it is a little old [this article](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/06/21/understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers/) by Michael Noll gives a good overview of the internal queues within the workers.

To answer your question. The ratio between the queues will not always be 2:1. The disruptor queues report their metrics averaged over the user configurable `topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs` so this will obscure some of the difference. Also all metrics are subject to a sample ratio, set by the `topology.stats.sample.rate` config variable - which by default is only 20% of transferred tuples, this can also cause the reported numbers to be off.

Also, depending on the code in your bolts, 1 input tuple may produce many output tuples so you would have to take this into account in any ratios you were calculating.

You refer to the stability of an equation in your question. The arrival rate is not based on any queuing theory equation and is simply the number of tuples that are put on the queue in a metric.bucket period divided by the period length in seconds. However, Storm does report a queue sojourn time metric. This is based on a very simple queuing theory equation that is not reliable for unstable queue systems and should be avoided.

Comment: thanks a lot. sorry for lack of timely reply. Spout instances in Storm  have a receive queue for receive the tuple form acker instances. therefore, the number of tuple that spout received should be equal to it send.